# "Trackchanges": respecting the equation environment

Tags: packages, equations, changes

I am using [trackchanges](http://trackchanges.sourceforge.net/) for monitoring changes in a LaTeX document.

I have a problem when compiling a trackchange tag with a equation environment embedded into it. Here is a .tex file which compiles

```
\documentclass[A4]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm, amssymb}
\usepackage{trackchanges}
\begin{document}

\addeditor{alexm}
\section{dog}
Hello, this is an example file. \add[alexm]{Here I add text}.
There is a tree\remove[alexm]{but I remove a cat}. My hair is 
\change[alexm]{green}{red}.

\end{document}
```

This file compiles fine and a .pdf is produced as it should be. But now with an equation being shown:

```
\documentclass[A4]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm, amssymb}
\usepackage{trackchanges}
\begin{document}
\addeditor{alexm}
\section{dog}
Hello, this is an example file. \add[alexm]{Here I add text}.
There is a tree\remove[alexm]{but I remove a cat}. My hair is 
\change[alexm]{green}{red}.

Now with an equation it fails, but why?
\add[alexm]{some text
\begin{equation}
1+1=2
\end{equation}
and some more text.}

\end{document}
```

This gives fatal compiling errors. Is there a way to keep it from failing, any protective tags? It doesn't matter if it doesn't display properly, as long as it compiles, since it is for draft purposes anyways, but it would be a bonus.

Comment: What are the errors it gives?  It would help if you could post a minimal file that can be compiled to give the errors you are experiencing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe the best solution here is to use `\protect`, so:

```
\add[alexm]{some text
\protect \begin{equation}
1+1=2
\end{equation}
and some more text.}
```

may meet your needs.  I've used `\protect` for things like the `itemize` environment as well.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out.  I could swear I tried it before posting my answer, but obviously I didn't.

Comment: thanks a ton!! Could you give any intuition about this solution as well? It would be an appretiated addition :)

Comment: @Vass I would refer to [this post](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4736/what-is-the-difference-between-fragile-and-robust-commands/4747#4747) regarding fragile/robust commands.

Answer (score 5):

The `trackchanges` package defines its `\add` command (roughly) to set the colour of its argument and pass it to the `\ul` command of the `soul` package for underlining. You simply can't pass any environment to the `\ul` command. (So it's not just equations that won't work; no environment will work.)  The only way around this, as far as I can see is to never put environments inside the `\add` command, but instead use `\add` commands around the added environments.

**Edit:** (Solution due to Matt Kolb) It seems that just protecting environments within the `\add` command actually works:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{trackchanges}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm, amssymb}
\begin{document}
\addeditor{alexm}
\section{dog}
Hello, this is an example file. \add[alexm]{Here I add text}.
There is a tree\remove[alexm]{but I remove a cat}. My hair is 
\change[alexm]{green}{red}.

Now with an equation it fails, but why?

\add[alexm]{New equation
\protect\begin{equation}
1+1=2
\end{equation}
End new equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks for explaining this, it makes sense even though my background is not wide enough to follow it all. So it means that I have to create discontinuous flow in the text with the track changes tags :( Well, if there is no other way.

Comment: @Vass See Matt's answer for a better solution (which you should accept instead of mine.)  I'll add it to mine as well.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, very good of you. What is this "\protect" command that does the magic?? It is not in the trackchanges documentation.

Comment: @Vass See [What is the difference between Fragile and Robust commands?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/4736/) for what `\protect` does.

Comment: thanks again. Can you tell me why the \protect command does not work with a \begin{comment} and \end{comment} environment inside a \remove tag? cheers