# Track changes to equations using the changes package

Tags: changes

Is it possible to track changes of equations using the [changes](http://texdoc.net/pkg/changes) package? Here is a small example of what I mean:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{changes}
\begin{document}
\noindent Using the changes package is it possible not only to delete \deleted{text}, but
also equations? For instance this one:
%\deleted{\protect
\begin{equation}
x = 1
\end{equation}
%}
\end{document}
```

When removing the commented text I get a compilation error, even when using "\protect" as suggested [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15850/trackchanges-respecting-the-equation-environment) when the same question was answered using a different package.

Comment: It seems `\deleted` cannot take a long argument (one that contains paragraphs, line breaks and the like.) The documentation states "You cannot markup more than one paragraph at a time. You cannot markup figures or tables as well."

Comment: Delete the equation text, not environment: `\begin{equation}\deleted{x=1}\end{equation}`.

Comment: @moewe I read that part, but I thought you could delete equations since it didn't mention this explicitly.

Comment: @ClaudioFiandrino Thank you for your suggestion. However, the changes package has a nice property in that when you are done modfying your text you can use "final" as an argument and `\usepackage[final]{changes}` will remove all the deleted or highlighted text. If you only delete the equation text, the equation number will still be there with the "final" argument.

Comment: Well, I suppose the documentation just forgot to mention that basically almost all environments are problematic for `\deleted`.